# 'Could not find method..' on custom actionbar - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm attempting to create a new custom bottom action bar. The visuals seem ok, however, adding an onClick to the inflated ImageView (from the RelativeLayout) throws a 'could not find method' error. I'm testing it with the textOnClickTest method below.

I'm basically trying to customize the spacing between the icons. The onClick doesn't seem to work though.

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_actionbar, null);

    relativeLayout.addView(view2);

    return true;
}
```

Test function:

```
public void textOnClickTest (){
    System.out.println("prints stuff");
}
```

bottom_action.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/action_bottom"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/layers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="textOnClickTest"
    android:src="@drawable/layers_icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

action_menu.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:title="Search"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/bottom_actionbar"
    android:icon="@drawable/layers_icon"
    android:numericShortcut="1"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item

    android:id="@+id/menuU"
    android:icon="@drawable/social_group"
    android:numericShortcut="2"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="u"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Top actionbar:

```
 mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.just_text, null);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(view);
```

just_text.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="testOnClickText"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try: view2.findViewBy(R.idlayers).setOnClickListener(new ... ) ?

Comment: changing the method to textOnClickTest(View view) worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textOnClickTest ()` method should accept a parameter of fype `View`. 
Something like this:

```
public void textOnClickTest (View view){
    //..
}
```

(As a side note, inflating that RelativeLayout in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` does not  seem an appropriate location. If you want something to happen when a menu option is clicked, then you should override `onOptionsItemSelected()`)

Comment: The View view worked. The top action bar causes the same error though. See edit.

Comment: Can't figure out. Put the layout of  R.layout.just_text too.

Comment: You have a typo. The method name is: `textOnClickTest()`, but in R.layout.just_text is: `testOnClickText()`. test vs text.

Comment: Typo indeed, but it's still crashing after the fix. I double checked the spelling again.

Comment: Crashing with the same error? Make sure the method `textOnClickTest()` is in the same activity where the `R.layout.just_text` is inflated.

Comment: They're both in the same activity: The inflation is in onCreate while textOnClickTest() is a method outside of onCreate but in the same class